# Issues Writing xpath objects with commas out to CSV in Python

Tags: python, csv, xpath

Building a web scraper for use internally on sites I manage and I am having issues outputting xpath lists that happen to include commas in the output string.  I know that I need to handle the commas inside the string lists differently than the commas that separate the values meant to be separated into columns

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-
import requests
from lxml import html
import urlparse
import collections
import csv
import time

# Settings
statingurl = 'http://www.somdomain.com'
domain = 'somedomain'

# filename
timestr = time.strftime("%m-%d-%Y-%H-%M-%S")
f = open('scrape-output\\'+domain+'-metadata-'+timestr+'.csv', 'a+')

# Create URL Queue, Set Start, Crawl
urls_queue = collections.deque()
urls_queue.append(statingurl)
found_urls = set()
found_urls.add(statingurl)

# Set Column Headers for the file
colheader = "URL Crawled, Title Tag, Meta Description, H1, H2, H3, H4, H5, H6, Image Source, Image Alt"
f.write(colheader)
f.write("\n")

while len(urls_queue):
    url = urls_queue.popleft()
    page_url = url
    print "\n"
    print "************************************************************"
    print "\n"

    # Use Requests to get Metadata
    if url.startswith(statingurl):
        print "Connecting to %s" % (url,)
        page = requests.get(url)
        tree = html.fromstring(page.content)
        print "\n"

    # Extract Metadata elements from the html tree
    title = tree.xpath('//title/text()')
    description = tree.xpath("//head/meta[@name='description']/@content")
    h1 = tree.xpath('//h1/text()')
    h2 = tree.xpath('//h2/text()')
    h3 = tree.xpath('//h3/text()')
    h4 = tree.xpath('//h4/text()')
    h5 = tree.xpath('//h5/text()')
    h6 = tree.xpath('//h6/text()')
    imgsrc = tree.xpath('//img/@src')
    imgalt = tree.xpath('//img/@alt')

    # Output Metadata
    print 'Found %s Title' % len(title) 
    print title,"\n"
    print 'Found %s Description' % len(description)
    print description,"\n"  
    print 'Found %s H1' % len(h1)   
    print h1
    print 'Found %s H2' % len(h2)   
    print h2
    print 'Found %s H3' % len(h3)   
    print h3
    print 'Found %s H4' % len(h4)   
    print h4
    print 'Found %s H5' % len(h5)   
    print h5
    print 'Found %s H6' % len(h6)   
    print h6    
    print '\n'
    print 'Found %s Image Paths' % len(imgsrc)
    print 'Images Src:'
    print imgsrc 
    print "\n"
    print 'Found %s Image Alt Tags' % len(imgsrc)   
    print 'Image Alt:'
    print imgalt
    print "\n"

    # Finds links on page; Add URL to Queue
    print "Looking for links"
    links = {urlparse.urljoin(page.url, url) for url in tree.xpath('//a/@href') if urlparse.urljoin(page.url, url).startswith('http')}

    print "Set difference to find new URLs"
    # Set difference to find new URLs
    for link in (links - found_urls):
        found_urls.add(link)
        urls_queue.append(link) 
    print '\n %s URLs in Queue' % len(urls_queue)

    # Write Output to file and repeat loop
    output = "%s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s, %s" % (page_url.encode('utf-8'), title, description, h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, imgsrc, imgalt)
    f.write(output)
    f.write('\n')
```

If someone could just help me understand say for the description value how to ensure that the  comma in the description object is parsed as a string complete with the comma in it, into the csv file, I would greatly appreciate it.  There is more work to do on this script past that, but that is my immediate issue.

Thanks.

Comment: use `csv` module or try to write every element in `" "` -`"%s", "%s", "%s"`. But you can get text with `"` and you have new problem :) Better use `csv` module.

Comment: @furas thanks for the quick reply.  being new to python what part of the csv module, or in what way should I be using the csv module? Is it writerows() is it something different entirely.  Also the option above writes the double quotes outside the list object in question
    `"['some',"data, is here']"`  what I need is `["some","data, is here"]` unless I am misunderstanding the reason the data is written improperly

Comment: `csv` module cares about commas, `"` and other thinks. And you don't need to use `%s, %s`.  `csv_writer.writerow(list_with_elements_or_headers)`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Use this in your code:

```
import csv
headers = ["URL Crawled", "Title Tag", "Meta Description", "H1",
           "H2", "H3", "H4", "H5", "H6", "Image Source", "Image Alt"]
f = open('file.csv', 'ab')
writer = csv.writer(f)
writer.writerow(headers)
writer.writerow(["some", "data, is here"])
```

Also, for parsing the web, it is better to use the `unicodecsv` module for handling unicode content.
You will have to install it using pip by doing `pip install unicodecsv`.

`unicodecsv` has the same functions as the `csv` module.

Once you've installed the `unicodecsv` module you just have to replace

`import csv`

by

`import unicodecsv`

And everything should work better.

Comment: a combination of the switching to unicodecsv and the writer.writerow() calls fixed the issue.   Thank you for your help!

Answer (score 0):

Consider using the `join()` method to concatenate xpath strings with double quotes in an effort to escape commas within strings:

```
output = '","'.join([page_url.encode('utf-8'), title, description, 
                     h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, imgsrc, imgalt])
f.write(output)
f.write('\n')
```

Or alternatively as suggested by others use the csv module. Do be aware of additional indentation because of the `with()`:

```
colheader = ['URL Crawled', 'Title Tag', 'Meta Description', 
             'H1', 'H2', 'H3', 'H4', 'H5', 'H6', 'Image Source', 'Image Alt']

with open('scrape-output\\'+domain+'-metadata-'+timestr+'.csv', 'w', newline='') as f:
    writer = csv.writer(f)    
    writer.writerow(colheader)

    while len(urls_queue):
       ...
       ...rest of loop code...
       ...
       writer.writerow([page_url.encode('utf-8'), title, description, 
                        h1, h2, h3, h4, h5, h6, imgsrc, imgalt])
```